# simple string.equals working incorrectly - Java

Tags: java, string, properties, string-comparison

Been racking my brains with this for ages now and it's just stumped me.

I have a simple string comparison:

```
public static void login() 
{
    isIncorrectInput = true;

    while (isIncorrectInput) 
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter your password: ");
        password = readLine();

        if (password.equals(currentUser.password))
        {
            isIncorrectInput = false;
            System.out.print("Successful login!");
        } 
        else 
        {
            System.out.print("Incorrect password. Please try again.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

So, 'password' is a String variable, currentUser is a instance of a User object which has a password property.

I've tried switching which object the method is called on: doesn't work. Tried ignoring the case: doesn't work. The passwords are DEFINITELY the same, I've stepped through it countless times, it's just returning false when it should be returning true.

What am I doing wrong!!?

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: You sure `readLine` doesn't include the newline?

Comment: Please include a `System.out.println(password);` and a `System.out.println(currentUser.password)` before the `if` statement and show us the result

Comment: Well, `String.equals()` definitely *does* work, so I'm pretty strongly convinced that the values are *not* the same. If you could provide a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem, that would really help...

Comment: Is the password property in the User object a String? Can you post your User class code please?

Comment: Could your readline method be returning a String with a newline character at the end?

Comment: Have you tried other methods? compareTo? compareToIgnoreCase?

Comment: just print the readLine() password, then you can identify the problem.

Comment: I tried other methods, and I printed out both password and currentUser.password and they were identical. I tried trim() on the password but I hadn't tried it on currentUser.password.. For some reason it works after that. I don't understand how the whitespace got there though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing readLine()'s body I can't be sure, but it is probably a whitespace issue. Try doing a `trim()` on the input before doing the comparison.

Comment: I had tried trim() on the password input, but I hadn't thought of trying it on the password property... It works after that. No idea where the whitespace would have come from though!

Comment: @NewStart It was not the whitespace but the end line character... trim() also delete end line characters.

Comment: Ah, I see.. I wasn't aware of that, I thought it only trimmed any form of whitespace!

Comment: @New Start : by documentation, every char that is a space (\u0020) or less (ch <= ' ') is considered a whitespace and is removed (from the beginning and end of the String).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you need to suppress the end line character.

```
password.replace(System.getProperty("line.separator"),"");
```

Answer (score 2):

probably the password variable is ended with '\n' char -
try:

```
password = password.trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

Where do you initalize "password" ? Is the password variable in the User-Class set and you have direct access (public etc.).

What does the "readLine()" methode do?
Maybe you miss a space character or a newline, also check if upper/lower case is the same.
Good luck.